# k edge-disjoint paths from v to u

Tags: algorithm

If there exist k edge-disjoint paths from u to v in graph G, then does there exist k edge-disjoint paths from v to u in G?

As per my thinking it can have k edge disjoint path in the residual graph G' and not in G. As the edges contains only unit capacity, so in G it will be saturating all the edges to get the maximum flow and hence we might not get k edge disjoint path in G. Is my logic correct?

Please correct me if I am wrong and what could be the other approach to this problem?

Comment: Directed graph or not? Do you mean "while u->v max flow is in progress, is there another flow v->u?" or "once the u->v flow finishes, can I use the same in reverse and be sure it is maximum"?

Comment: this question would rather belong to http://math.stackexchange.com/. As for the question itself: This can be solved a lot simpler: If the Graph is directed: sure. Else: the existence of a path from `u` to `v` doesn't guarantee the existence of a path in the reverse direction, so no

Comment: [Menger's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger's_theorem) - *"Given a directed graph G with nodes u, v the maximum number of
edge-disjoint u-v paths equals the minimum number of edges whose
removal separates u from v."*

If the direct u->v traffic doesn't knock out any links in v->u, then the v->u problem is equivalent of finding the maximum flow from v->u as if the u->v flow doesn't happen.

Comment: It is a directed graph. So does it mean that if we remove the edges from u->v according to Menger's theoram and if it disrupts the link between v->u, then v->u has k edge-points?