# Proof of having k edge-disjoint paths there and back

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, proof, max-flow

I have been trying to prove this for a decent amount of time, but nothing is coming to my mind. Anybody have some tips? I'd be happy to see an explanation.

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824058/k-edge-disjoint-paths-from-v-to-u) question on StackOverflow, that says this:

> If the direct u->v traffic doesn't knock out any links in v->u, then
> the v->u problem is equivalent of finding the maximum flow from v->u
> as if the u->v flow doesn't happen.

He describes how it can be solved, but still there is no answer to the question that the author asked.

So, the problem is:

Given a directed graph, at each vertex the number of incoming and outgoing edges is the same. Let there be **k** edge-disjoint paths from **b** to **a** in this graph.

How can I prove that it also contains k edge-disjoint paths from **a** to **b**?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try to argue about the general case where the graph is a multi-graph (i.e. can have multi-edges and loops).

*Note:* Following the convention that two copies of an edge count towards in and degree twice. And a loop count towards both in and out degree once. Also assuming when you say paths, you mean simple paths.

Using induction on the number of vertices in the graph **G**.

**Base case:** **G** has only vertices **a** and **b**.

Now as there are **k** edge-disjoint paths from **a** to **b**, all of them are simply **k** copies of the edge *a->b*. Thus to have in and out degrees same for both vertices there have to be **k** copies of *b->a*, and thus the claim holds.

**Induction** *G* has *n >=1* vertices apart from **a** and **b**.

Let the nth vertex be **u**. Let in-degree of **u**, same as its out-degree be *d*. Let the *d* vertices with edges "going into" **u** be *s1,s2,..,sd* and similarly the *d* vertices with edges going out from **u** be *t1,t2,..,td* (note all these vertices may not be unique). Just pair these vertices up. Say *si* with *ti* (1<=*i*<=d). Now just "short-circuit" the vertex *u*, i.e. rather than having the edge *si->u->ti*, just have *si->ti*. Let the new graph be **G'**. It is trivial to see in and out degree of vertices are still the same in **G'** (as it was in **G**). And it is not hard to argue that the new graph still has **k** disjoint paths from **a** to **b**. Additionally **G'** has one less vertex. So apply inductive hypothesis, and claim holds for **G'**. Lastly not hard to check again, un-short circuiting *u* still keeps the claim intact for **G**.